# ImportError: cannot import name 'interface' from 'brownie'

Tags: python, brownie

I was trying to implement [this script](https://github.com/brownie-mix/aave-flashloan-mix/blob/master/scripts/get_weth.py) to be able to wrap ETH into wETH.

So, I installed Brownie by running `pip3 install eth-brownie`.

However, I am having trouble importing `interface` in the first line of the script: `from brownie import accounts, config, network, interface`.

When it's run, I get the following error message:

```
from brownie import accounts, config, network, interface
ImportError: cannot import name 'interface' from 'brownie' (/home/blackwidow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/__init__.py)
```

It appears I am not the only person with this issue as [this has been reported in the past with no apparent solution](https://gitter.im/eth-brownie/community?at=60182fa784e66b7f7ec55c77).

Comment: Do you have an `interface` folder?

Comment: Could you download brownie with `pipx` instead of `pip`?

Comment: @PatrickCollins  Am I supposed to find `interface` folder in `.brownie` folder? If so, no, I only have `accounts` `ethpm` and `packages`.  I do have `interfaces` folder along with `build` `contracts` `reports` `scripts` and `tests` folders when i run `brownie init`  Also, I have tried both `pipx install eth-brownie` and `pip install eth-brownie`.  One thing i noticed is, if I use `pip`, it does compile the python script with `from brownie import accounts` but it does not if I had used `pipx`. They both regardless recognize `brownie` if I enter `brownie` in the terminal. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

dude check the run command it should be

```
brownie run scripts/get_weth.py --network kovan
```

and **NOT**

```
python scripts/get_weth.py --network kovan
```

I made the same mistake :P